# AWS IoT Rule SELECT does not working with a 'hex' string as JSON key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

I have an input payload like this.

```
{
    "state" : {
        "0x1234" : {
            "value" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

When I use SELECT state.**0x1234**.value FROM ****, it prompts error message. It seems SELECT does not work in this way. But my JSON format is totally valid. Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the error please, because what you've shared should work with the AWS IoT SELECT functionality?

Comment: "Failed to update rule. Expected 'AS' or ',' 0x1234.value FROM ..(less important)... "

Comment: I guess may be caused by aws use the key as a object, while 0x1234 is not a value name for variable.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's a bug, either because it's an undocumented limitation or because it's something that needs implementing (and worth reporting to AWS Support).

But I think you can work around it using the [get](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-get) function:

```
SELECT get(get(state, "0x1234"), "value") AS theValue FROM the/topic
```

Comment: I tried AS, it is the same. If I replace '0x1234' by 'B0x1234'. It can pass.

Comment: Add _0x1234 or $0x1234 also fails, the key can't start with '_', '$' or numeric.

Comment: OK- I've changed my answer to use the primitive `get` which might work.